# Generating efficient fast reports on amounts of data on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

I'm really confused about how or what AWS services to use for my case.

I have a web application which stores user interaction events. Currently these events are stored on a RDS table. Each event contains about 6 fields like timestamp, event type, userID, pageID, etc etc. Currently I have millions of event records on each account schema. When I try to generate reports out of this raw data - the reports are extremely slow since I do complex aggregation queries over long time period. a report of a time period of 30 days might take 4 minutes to generate on RDS.

Is there any way to make these reports running MUCH faster? I was thinking about storing the events on DynamoDB, but I cannot run such complex queries on the data, and to do any attribute based sorting.

Is there a good service combination to achieve this? Maybe using RedShift, EMP, Kinesis?

Comment: Might also be useful to include some example queries you are trying on RS?.I'm doing something similar, and found my queries from previous DBs (MySQL in my case) ran rather slowly until re-written & data re-partitioned. An aggregation over 100M rows for me takes about 10s on our cluster. Perhaps you don't need to move away.

Comment: I'm running an aggregation over an aggregation. For instance - every interaction record contains these fields: session, type, timestamp, product. First I select all the records with type=N and timestamp between T1 and T2, and I aggregate and group by session AND product. Then I aggregate the results again be specific comparison conditions.
The queries are VERY heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Redshift is your solution.

I'm working with a dataset that generates about 2.000.000 new rows each day and I made really complex operations on it. You could take advance of Redshift sort keys, and order your data by date.

Also if you do complex aggregate functions I really recommend to denormalize all the information and insert it in only one table with all the data. Redshift uses a very efficient, and automatic, column compression you won't have problems with the size of the dataset.

Comment: Thanks Iñaki for your answer. 
I read a little bit about Amazon RedShift and I noticed that this is a very efficient tool for complex queries on a large amount of data.
The problem is the pricing.
I collect about 1 million new data items per day on DynamoDB. Every day on a new table.
If I perform a daily append to RedShift table, I'll end up with huge amounts on data on RedShift which is very expensive.

Comment: Hello Forepick. If I were you I'll give it a try. Load all your data to it and see how big it gets. You'll be surprised because if your data has columns with a lot of similar info (like events are) the compresion is awsome. A 0.5Gb csv file of stats may only use 30 or 50mb of storage. You could test it paying only one or two hours of redshift.

Comment: Thanks Iñaki! You recommend denormalizing data before inserting into Redshift; is this common? I would have thought that because redshift is so efficient we could just run complex JOIN queries inside Redshift to do the denormalization. (I'm trying to figure out if it's common to do a Transform step on CSVs representing relational DB tables before those CSVs get loaded into Redshift, and your comment suggested that this is common practice for complex relations.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My usual solution to problems like this is to have a set of routines that rollup and store the aggregated results, to various levels in additional RDS tables. This transactional information you are storing isn't likely to change once logged, so, for example, if you find yourself running daily/weekly/monthly rollups of various slices of data, run the query and store those results, not necessarily at the final level that you will need, but at a level that significantly reduces the # of rows that goes into those eventual rollups. For example, have a daily table that summarizes eventtype, userid and pageId one row per day, instead of one row per event (or one row per hour instead of day) - you'll need to figure out the most logical rollups to make, but you get the idea - the goal is to pre-summarize at the levels that will reduce the amount of raw data, but still gives you plenty of flexibility to serve your reports.

You can always go back to the granular/transactional data as long as you keep it around, but there is not much to be gained by constantly calculating the same results every time you want to use the data.

Comment: Yes, Storing intermediate results for speeding up the final results is the way to go !

Comment: Thanks E.J for your details answer.
Well I'm afraid in my case saving the aggregation will be more challenging. Let me describe the case.
My app let customers to manager online stores. Some of my customers have about million register products on their account, and tons of user interactions, abut 50M per month!

If I save daily aggregations per account per product (which I must if the reports are generated between selected dates), I end up with 1 Million new records per day for big accounts!  This will choke my RDS instance in no time!